# Check if page has subpages

Tags: pages, menus, wp-list-pages, child-pages

I'm try to build a menu with `wp_list_pages()` that must work like this:

```
Main Page  
  -Subpage1  
  -Subpage2
```

I check if the Page has_subpage and i can see the 2 subpages when i'm in the Parent but when i'm visit one of the subpages i don't see anything.
So, what i can do to check if page has subpages to get the same list of pages in the subpage(s)?

How i use it:
in the functions i check if the Page has_subpage,

```
function has_subpage (){
global $post;
$pages = get_pages("sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&child_of={$post->ID}");
if ($pages) return TRUE;
}
```

and in my template i call the menu (list of subpages),

```
<?php if (is_page() && has_subpage()) { ?>

    <?php
      if($post->post_parent) {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0$sort_column=menu_order");
      $title_heading = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
      }

      else {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
      $title_heading = get_the_title($post->ID);
      }
      if ($children) { ?>

      <?php echo $children; ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

the problem is inside has_subpage() function, cause if i don't use it i get the pages correct,
maybe i'm missing something here?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the parent page id to the `wp_list_pages` function instead of the global `$post->ID` in your subpages.

```
function wpse33151_getSubpages() {      
    global $post;

    $parents = get_post_ancestors($post->post_id);
    krsort($parents);
    $parents = array_merge(array(), $parents);

    if (is_home() || is_single()) {
        $id = get_option('page_for_posts');
        $parent = get_post_ancestors($id);
        $id = $parent[0];
    } elseif($parents) {
        $id = $parents[0];
    } else {
        $id = $post->ID;
    }

    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=' . $id . '&echo=0');
    $out = null;

    if ($children) {
        $out = '<div id="subpages" class="widget-container">';
        $out .= '<h3 class="widget-title"><a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '">' . get_the_title($id) . '</a></h3>';
        $out .= '<ul>';
        $out .= $children;
        $out .= '</ul>';
        $out .= '</div>';
    }

    return $out;
}
```